# Mysql- Add days to date with different format

Tags: mysql, database, dateadd

I have to add days in my date column and I have date format as `m/d/Y`. For example, 06/10/2017
I have tried `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD('06/10/2017',INTERVAL 14 DAY), '%m/%d/%Y');` but it is not giving me any output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str_to_date`:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('06/10/2017', '%m/%d/%Y'),INTERVAL 14 DAY);
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b278/20)

---

Based on your comment, use `date_format` to reformat it as you did in your post:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('06/10/2017', '%m/%d/%Y'),
                            INTERVAL 14 DAY), '%m/%d/%Y');
```